# Javascript setTimeout while loading from XML into Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have been struggling with this code for quite some time.
I am loading an XML into Google Maps and Geocoding addresses from the XML.
I need to add a delay to the code when there are too many addresses to look up at once.

Here is my entire code for doing this

I need to have it load from the xml file with a delay, as it is it loads it all at once and the Geocoder can not handle that many requests when the XML is large. The XML file is changing continuously so it needs to be reloaded and re-Geocoded. It only becomes a problem when the XML file becomes larger, which is when I need it to work the most.

I have placed the delay around **`geocoder.getLocations(address,createMarker);`** but the address variable contains all the addresses so it does not delay it.  If i only place the delay around **`var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");`** it does not pass the **`i`** variable to the function. Any help anyone can give would be greatly appreciated.

```
    // create marker
    function createMarker(response) 
    { 
        var place = response.Placemark[0];
        var point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],
                                    place.Point.coordinates[0]);
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click",function()
            {
                marker.openInfoWindowHtml(place.address);
            });
            map.addOverlay(marker);
    }

      // Create new map object
       var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));  
       map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
       map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
       map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
       map.addMapType(G_PHYSICAL_MAP);
       map.setCenter(new GLatLng(49.923068,-119.437981), 10);
       var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

     // Download the data in active.xml
    GDownloadUrl("active.xml", function(data) 
    {

        var xml = GXml.parse(data);
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('INC');
        setTimeout( function()
            {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)    
        {
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");   
                    geocoder.getLocations(address,createMarker);    
                }
            },200);         
    });
```

Comment: This is Google Maps API v2, not v3.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");          
  function (innerAddress, j) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        geocoder.getLocations(innerAddress,createMarker);    
      }, 200 * j);
  }(address, i);
}
```

This should space out your requests to the geocoder.